# New to TDD, Unit test for Null String

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I am new to TDD and I am little confuse how to proceed. I am creating a login feature (ASP.NET Webform) and I like to create a unit test to check for loginId and PAssword is not null.

In order to achieve my task, I started like this:

```
    [Test] 
    public void MethodForTest_StringNotNull()
    {
        string expected="asdf";
        Login log=new Login();
        Assert.IsNotNull(expected,log.UserId);

    }
```

Please let me know if it's the right approach.

Thanks,

Comment: What is it that you want to test exactly? Are you trying to test whether the `UserId` property isn't null upon creating a `Login` instance? Please be more specific

Comment: I'm a little confused why you expect your UserId of a newly opened form to be "asdf".

Comment: I would like to test the login Feature on my website. User will provide loginId and password from the UI but on the backend I like to create a unit test for it. To create a unit test I have listed these as my task. 1- UserId must not be null 2-Password must not be null 3-UserId provided is pulling the correct information from the DB to authenticate the user.

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about what the `Login` class does. How will you be interacting with the class (e.g., which methods will be called)? What are you expectations for each kind of interaction?

Comment: login class connect to the database and authenticate the user. It takes loginId and password as an input.

Comment: Which method will you call to log the user in? What happens if I pass a null password?

Comment: I think that is my question, how to check that the user has provided both UserId and password and they are not null.

Comment: If you're trying to test the end user's interaction with the system, then you're not looking for a unit test at all. You're looking for a functional test, and NUnit is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Assert.IsNotNull(object, string)` overload (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243704.aspx))

So with the code you've shown you are testing if `expected` is not `null,` if it is, show the `log.UserId` as the error message.

To actually test your web forms code, you can look at a design pattern called [Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx). By using such a pattern, you decouple your user interface from your code behind. This allows you to fake a user interface where you can set dummy values in your user interface for values like user name and password. You can then verify that your code does the correct thing.

The same is true for your database. If your unit test is using the database you are actually creating 
an integration test. That's a different type of test that should be handled differently.

I wrote a blog post about some of these concepts a while ago. I hope it can help you: [Unit Testing, hell or heaven?](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2012/03/unit-testing-hell-or-heaven.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are different levels of testing you can use.

**Unit Test**

Your example code is a unit test (as long as `Login` does not call a database, otherwise that would make this an integration test). A unit test for the `Login` class in this respect wouldn't be of much value, since it does not look to do much (though, we haven't seen the code for `Login`, so that's an assumption).

**Integration Test**

This type of test means you are interacting with an external "thing" e.g. databases, file system, network, etc. Without seeing the code for `Login`, it's impossible for me to state whether an integration test is any use for you here.

**Functional Test**

Here you can use a tool such as [Watin](http://watin.org/) to drive an actual browser that will navigate to your website and perform any command you have asked it to do. So you could navigate to the login page, enter a username and password, click "OK" and then verify in your test that the expected username and password were given.

It sounds like you need to use a functional test here, since you want to ensure that the given user input is what you expect it to be at the serve level.

In all the above test types, you can still use NUnit to drive the tests, so don't worry about that. With Watin, you simply download it and include it in your project, as the tool's documentation states.

There are other web driver type tools available, but `Watin` is the one that came off the top of my head.